# Delete control after animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to remove the control `addServer` after an animation. How could I do this? If I have to do this with an Task or Thread, how do I Invoke the right way to be able to remove the element?

My delete method looks like this:

```
Main.Children.Remove(addServer);
addServer = null;
```

**Edit**

My final solution looks like this:

```
// Adding a evh to the storyboard calling after the animation has finished
// Used a lambada to pass my control as a param in my delete method
storyboard.Completed += (s, ea) => DeleteAddServerPanel(storyboard, addServer);
storyboard.Begin();
```

And my delete method

```
private void DeleteAddServerPanel(Storyboard storyboard, AddServer addServer)
{
    Main.Children.Remove(addServer);
    addServer = null;
}
```

This makes it possible to remove the control without the need of an seperate thread so I don't even need to invoke.

Comment: What do you think the problem is with your method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are asking is how to do that on another thread other than main thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      DispatcherPriority.Background,
      new Action(() => Main.Children.Remove(addServer);));
```

However, note that I personally do not advise UI manipulation on another thread in this fashion unless it is the only option.

Comment: Well is there another solution to do this? Something like an eventhandler if the control has been deleted? I don't know if there's another solution.

Comment: @chris579, your requirement is not clear for me, but WPF doesn't give any deleted kind of event, but you could use Unloaded event.

Comment: You're right but I did it in another way. I update my post.